# Cómo realizar una búsqueda por rango de fecha DD/MM/AAAA en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo en mi Base de datos el campo fecha como tipo Varchar que guarda la fecha en DD/MM/AAAA. Deseo realizar una consulta en MYSQL que me arroje el resultado comprendido en un rango de fecha. como puedo realizar esta consulta en MYSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En ese caso puedes convertir el campo `varchar` que almacena la fecha a `fecha` al usarlo como condición en la `query`. Aunque lo más aconsejable sería cambiar el campo a formato fecha, ya que si son tablas grandes la query puede resultar lenta.

Ejemplo:
**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  fec VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO test (id,fec) VALUES (1,'01/10/2019');
INSERT INTO test (id,fec) VALUES (2,'15/10/2019');
INSERT INTO test (id,fec) VALUES (3,'15/11/2019');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE str_to_date(fec, '%d/%m/%Y') > str_to_date('10/10/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') 
AND str_to_date(fec, '%d/%m/%Y') > str_to_date('29/10/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') 
;

| id  | fec        |
| --- | ---------- |
| 3   | 15/11/2019 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Hola Carmen, muchas gracias por su respuesta. Lo estoy intentando así y efectivamente cuando ejecuto el query en mysql ejecuta perfectamente, pero cuando intento correrla desde PHP no arroja ningún resultado.

Comment: $consultaBeneficio1= sprintf("SELECT tbl_personal.id_empleado, tbl_valor_beneficios.fecha_beneficio, Sum(tbl_valor_beneficios.valor) AS montoFinal, tbl_personal.nombre_completo, tbl_valor_beneficios.id_beneficio FROM tbl_valor_beneficios INNER JOIN tbl_personal ON tbl_valor_beneficios.id_empleado = tbl_personal.id_empleado WHERE  tbl_valor_beneficios.id_beneficio = 1 AND tbl_personal.id_empleado = '$id_empleado' AND str_to_date(fecha_beneficio, '%d/%m/%Y') > str_to_date('$fechaInicial', '%d/%m/%Y') AND str_to_date(fecha_beneficio, '%d/%m/%Y') < str_to_date('$$fechaFinal', '%d/%m/%Y')");

Comment: @TaylorAsprillaBohórquez comprueba que el formato de los campos $fechaInicial y $fechaFinal (sobra un $) son los adecuados para conformar correctamente la query, puedes hacer un echo de la consulta y ver si funciona en base de datos.

Comment: estoy residiendo las variables $fechaInicial y $fechaFinal por medio de un formulario y que envían por _GET. Estas las recibo en un archivo que se llama imprimir.php. Hasta allí las variables llegan con los valores en formato d/m/Y. Luego hago un include de imprimir.php en el archivo busqueda.php (donde tengo las consultas) es allí donde tengo el inconveniente porq las query de búsqueda funcionan bien en Mysql pero en el PHP es como si se perdieran los valores de las variables. ¿Cómo puedo enviar esas variables del archivo imprimir.php al archivo busqueda.php?

Comment: @TaylorAsprillaBohórquez tendrías que enviar las variables de imprimir.php a busqueda.php. Puedes procesar el formulario en imprimir.php y una vez procesado redirigir a busqueda php con las variables que necesites.

Comment: Gracias Carmen. Funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Lo suyo es que al guardar cada valor en la base de datos sea con su tipo si es un numero que sea tipo int, si es una fecha que sea un datetime, etc... Pero ya que lo tienes como string (VARCHAR) la unica solución que veo es hacerle un LIKE a dicha columna de esta manera:

```
SELECT column1, column2, Fecha FROM table_name WHERE Fecha LIKE '%10/05/2019%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Como te apuntan las otras respuestas, para cualquier tipo de dato siempre es mejor opción guardarlo en un tipo de dato compatible.

Para buscar fechas dentro de un rango, la mejor opción es utilizar la operación BETWEEN  AND . Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM MITABLE WHERE STR_TO_DATE(MiCampoFecha, '%d%m%Y') BETWEEN INIT_DATE AND END_DATE
```

Un saludo